# How to loop through Java List<Object[]> object in JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, json, list

Controller

```
List<Object[]> permissionList = new ArrayList();
 //fill  permissionList with list of object ayyays (objetct[0] = permission id, object[1] = permission)
 model.addAttribute("permissionList", permissionList);
```

jsp

```
var allpermissionList = "${permissionList}";

$.each(allpermissionList, function (index, av) {
   var id = av[0];
   vat name=av[1];
   //set values to div element
});
```

i can't loop through my list with js $each()... av[0] and av[1] cannot cannot obtain.

Comment: And in what language is this ?

Comment: Read the generated source and you will see what the problem is.  You need to use JSON.

Comment: @adeneo The to part is Java (OP says JSP), the bottom part is JavaScript.

Comment: controller is java spring controller problem is with loop through my list in jsp page.

Comment: `console.log(allpermissionList)`, if that's a string you need to `var list = JSON.parse(allpermissionList)`

Comment: I have never used JSP, but just a guess: what if you remove the quotes around the variable, e.g. `var allpermissionList = ${permissionList}`?

Comment: First at all, try to print `${permissionList}` by posting it in some part of your code. After that, you'll understand that you should first parse it as a JSON object and then you could easily use it in JavaScript side.

Comment: var allpermissionList = "[[Ljava.lang.Object;@31131b0e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5d554d4d, [Ljava.lang.Object;@b462a1a, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2b7616be, [Ljava.lang.Object;@55cf2a3c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@60067362]";
       

i checked the page source and it is shown the var allpermissionList = "${permissionList}"; as above..

Comment: This is JSP and it's horrible. Open an API and fetch the list as a proper json blob.

Comment: Ok, now you understand what you're getting? JavaScript doesn't understand Java directly, so instead saving a `List<Object[]>` as your request attribute (in your model variable or wherever), save it as a structure that can be easily read by JavaScript like a String generated by a JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java code runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. They are very different languages and do not interoperate out of the box. When you need to pass data from Java to JavaScript, the easiest is to serialize it to JSON using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for example.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
model.addAttribute("permissionList", om.writeValueAsString(permissionList));
```

and in the JSP:

```
var allpermissionList = ${permissionList};
```

Note that not all Java object are serializable to JSON so the objects in your list should be simple Java types (String, Number...) or POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

I got resolved .. thanks all.

Controller

```
List<Object[]> permissionList = new ArrayList();
// load values
List<Map<String, String>> listAll = new ArrayList<>();
   if (permissionList != null && permissionList.size() > 0) {
       for (Object[] objects : allPermissions) {
           Map map = new HashMap();
           map.put("id",objects[0]);
           map.put("permName", objects[1]);
           listAll.add(map);
        }
    }

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String permissionList = mapper.writeValueAsString(listAll);
model.addAttribute("permissionList", permissionList);
```

Jsp

```
 var allpermissionList = eval(${permissionList});
  $.each(allpermissionList, function (index, permission) {
     var id = permission.id;
     var name = permission.name;

 });
```