# How to iterate Java list in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I have an ArrayList which contains  Object in my ManagedBean like below

```
List<TargetData> targetList=new ArraList<TargetData>();
```

i want to take this list in javascript like below

```
var list = "#{settingsBean.targetist}";
```

I tried to iterate like

```
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
}
```

But i am unable to iterate list in javascript.Can any one pz help me.How can i iterate the above list in javascript

Comment: you don't put java into javascript. You serialize your java stuff into JSON, and embed that into javascript. json IS javascript, so essentially you'd be converting your java object into its javascript representation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through Java List<Object\[\]> object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499083/how-to-loop-through-java-listobject-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into a JSON format from the Java end and then read it in on the Javascript side. You can do so through this link here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499541/3421811

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Java and Javascript don't execute on the same machines - Java executes on the server, and Javascript on the client. So your client is never going to be able to interate over your bean unless you send it via web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You  should not be mixing them together as they two are entirely different from each other. Whatever we are doing in javascript we are doing it on the client(browser) and whatever is being done in java its being done in jvm or server. As above posts suggests either convert your list in json and send the json which you can parse in javascript. Or if you are using it on web with some framework like tiles then you can simply return your list to your tile -> iterate it and then return the complete jsp content to your ajax method which you can render on the page .

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)